# Unable to call kotlin extension function from java

Tags: java, kotlin

I know kotlin extention functions are compile as static function using fileName as class name with Kt suffix. Problem is my single String parameter function is asking for two String parameters when invoked from java code.

*Extention function is in **KUtils** file*

```
fun String.extractDigits(strValue: String): String {
    val str = strValue.trim { it <= ' ' }
    var digits = ""
    var chrs: Char
    for (i in 0..str.length - 1) {
        chrs = str[i]
        if (Character.isDigit(chrs)) {
            digits += chrs
        }
    }
    return digits
}
```

*Calling java code*

```
KUtilsKt.extractDigits("99PI_12345.jpg")
```

*Compile Time Error Message :*

Error:(206, 42) error: method extractDigits in class KUtilsKt cannot be applied   to given types;
required: String,String
found: String
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Please Help
Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that the receiving instance is encoded as a parameter. So:

```
fun String.extractDigits(strValue: String): String {...}
```

Becomes (`javap` output):

```
public static final java.lang.String extractDigits(java.lang.String, java.lang.String);
```

But you're passing only a single argument to the function.

I don't quite understand why you're using an extension function here, I'd expect to see the receiving instance used instead of passing a separate value:

```
fun String.extractDigits(): String {
    val str = this.trim { it <= ' ' } // Using `this`, i.e. the receiving instance
    var digits = ""
    var chrs: Char
    for (i in 0..str.length - 1) {
        chrs = str[i]
        if (Character.isDigit(chrs)) {
            digits += chrs
        }
    }
    return digits
}
```

Then, in Java, you can call it like you tried, and in Kotlin like this:

```
val str = "123blah4"
println(str.extractDigits()) // prints 1234
```

Comment: I use a library which has an extension function. I'm not able access that extension function in java classes, meaning that the corresponding java class file is not created. But, I'm able to access it in Kotlin classes.